# open shift application not displayed on web console

Tags: openshift, openshift-web-console

In open shift account i had hosted one word press app

"http://music-logavdm2.rhcloud.com"

I also tried the open shift client tool to list the app

app music but that also tells the app does not exist

Yesterday i update the blog but today that application not displayed on the web console. and also the

"http://music-logavdm2.rhcloud.com"

not found found DNS address error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your app may have been removed (possibly due to  [OpenShift ToS](https://www.openshift.com/legal/terms.html) infringement).

In that case, you would receive a notification email with a reason of the removal. You can try [contacting](https://developers.openshift.com/en/help.html) OpenShift support, if you received no such email.